# Problem with using admob and image_picker package in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, gradle, admob

I am getting a strange error.
When I use:

dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
...
}

I get the following error while building the apk:

[image]

but when I use:

dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
...
}

The image picker does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'
in project level gradle file.

Comment: The same Gradle + Admob + image_picker issue still persists with gradle 4.1.0 one year later. Unfortunately there is no error notification when building with 4.1.0. What makes it hard to debug is that the debug build works fine, but the release build breaks. (Also, this is why I love stackoverflow, I first thought this issue would be too specific to find resources on it :))
And bless you for answering your own question, just realized!